# Match all urls in a domain except queries

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I wish to match (java regex) all urls belonging to a certain domain except the ones looking like a query string.

For e.g. I wish to match

```
http://www.thehindu.com/arts/music/marrying-keys-to-chips/article4061904.ece
```

But avoid

```
http://www.thehindu.com/arts/music?article=23417
```

I tried the following but it allows both the above patterns.

```
+^http://www\.thehindu\.com([^\?=])*
```

Comment: Please elaborate, I am not able to understand what you want to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(^|\s)http:\/\/www\.thehindu\.com([^\?])*(\s|$)
```

Where the (^|\s) and (\s|$) are delimiters you expect between urls. Add more in those if you need.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
if (yourString.matches("(http://)?www\\.thehindu\\.com[^\\?=]*") {
    // match --> doesn't look like a query
} else {
    // no match --> looks like a query or completely different url
}
```

Comment: This seems to work with `matches()`. The lookahead wasn't necessary I guess.

Comment: I have a constraint. Cannot deal with these programatically.

Comment: what do you mean with that? is my answer sufficient for you, or not?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose regexp isn't required, try looking for question mark `?`.